# categories not visible in left sidebar magento

Tags: magento

I was using amasty improved navigation extension for filters in Magento.
 After removing this extension categories are not visible on left sidebar anymore.

I am using ultimo theme. 
In admin under `manage categories`, my categories are `is anchor : yes` but the categories are still not displaying in the left sidebar.

Comment: Did you Try reindexing  ?

Comment: yes. i did indexing and clear cache. even delete var folder too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog>Improved Navigation > Setting` and configure following as per your theme layout options.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: i removed amasty. i Want magento default category navigation.